# How to avoid losing Post request data

Tags: java, android, post, okhttp

Sometimes when I post some data if connection is turned off or there is a problem I lose the data and that's not good ,I'm looking for a way to save the data in the background or something like this and it will send automatically when there is a connection and in the same time waiting I must be able to use the application, any ideas ?

```
  Post PostContact = new Post();
  json = PostContact.ContactJson(id_device1,id_device2);
  response = PostContact.post("url", json);
```

Comment: you can check when there is internet connection or not before calling server API, if not connected then add listener to detect network connection, when you will get internet it will notify you and you can call pending apis

Comment: @NehaK yes this is what I do , I save the data and I will post it when there is connection ,but I don't know how can I make this listener , I run a service so the app work in background so this listener will execute when there is internet and it will post the data saved , But I do not have any idea about this connection listener !

Comment: Use ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION https://medium.com/ki-labs-engineering/monitoring-wifi-connectivity-status-part-1-c5f4287dd57

Answer (score 1):

HTTP request functions as below

Client make requests

Server reply responses

They don't really care about what happens in between. This means that once the client has done the request after that is like a black box. If the server's connection is interrupted while your request is coming the data will be corrupted, and since there is no both-ways communication the client won't know about it to re-send the request.

the best option is to create a transaction:

Client creates a unique transaction ID for the request and attach to the Rest call

Server receives the request, check the transaction log for previous calls with the same id.

if it is a new transaction, server stores this transaction ID in a log with a status 'pending'. Server then processes the request. Server updates the transaction log status to 'processed'. Server then sends the response to the client and stores response in the transaction log

If it is an old transaction, server resend response to client

Client receives response, client sends transaction completed signal to the server.

Server removes/updates transaction log to 'finished'

Failure in the 5th step, the client can resend the request with the same transaction id, without the risk of duplicate records